# UK County Map & Image Maps

Tags: html, maps

I need a map of the UK showing counties that the user can then click on. I've determined that without using flash I can use image maps, and I have a large png county map that I can use.

However, to execute this I would be spending the better half of a day clicking dots on the lines between counties, and would have to repeat the exercise should I make a mistake, browser crashes, or the results arent satisfactory, or the image needs resizing.

Is there an easier way to pull this off without paying out or a large dose of repetitive clicking?

Answer (score 1):

This [Dundas Maps support page](http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=1013) provides a lengthy list of resources for (mostly) free map data.

Comment: In the somewhat unlikely event that you have access to CorelDraw, Adobe Illustrator, or similar, you could convert a pre-made SVG image (such as at http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:SVG_maps_of_the_United_Kingdom or 
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:SVG_maps_of_England) to an image map with the HTML export filter.

Comment: Indeed I have Illustrator CS4 here, sadly that Dundas Maps page hasnt got the kind of map I need, and I wouldnt be able to use those formats anyway